# Tourist on ICT Short term visa?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens

I am an Indian citizen. I have ICT tier 2 short term UK visa valid till June 2015. I was in UK for 6 months. My assignment got over and I came back to India in Jan 2015. I want to visit UK again as a tourist now. I don't have any assignment there anymore. Can I visit UK on the same visa? Or I need to apply separate tourist visa?

Comment: Is there something on your visa like amount of entries? I don't know if this is the case on all visas.

Comment: Did you try asking at the UK consulate?

Comment: @ Lewis Yes, it says multiple entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a multiple ICT T2 visa & you're eligible to travel back to UK again but as you don't have any assignment here in UK, its better that you apply for a separate tourist visa.
**Why so?** The UK immigration officers will ask you the purpose of your visit & when you'll say "just a friendly visit" or something like that, it would be a violation of your ICT visa.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Waqqas. That was helpful and exactly same as told by VFS office.